# Writing clean urls with .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting, clean-urls

**Update** - Alright thanks everyone for your tests, it really helped. The code is good. My problem was not having absolute "/" links. (Due to moving from public_html folder).

Only 2 concerns i have now.

1.) Replace "^achilles" with "^([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)" and thumbnails wont appear (parameter data is not being carried???)

2.) How can I make http://funkygames.co/games/achilles/achilles/1 become even shorter like http://funkygames.co/games/achilles Or are the parameters absolutely mandatory.

```
# Turn Rewrite Engine On
RewriteEngine on     

# Set the base to /games/ so we need not include it in the rules
RewriteBase /games/

#Rewrite for achilles.php?games_path=xxxxxxxxxx.yyy&category_id=zzz
RewriteRule ^achilles/(.*)/([0-9]+) $1.php?games_path=$1.swf&category_id=$2 [NC,L]
```

---

Where i learned: www.youtube.com/watch?v=1pbAV6AU99I

---

**SOLVED!** Thanks to you guys. 
Solution:

```
# Turn Rewrite Engine On
RewriteEngine on     

# Set the base to /games/ so we need not include it in the rules
RewriteBase /games/

#Rewrite for achilles.php?games_path=xxxxxxxxxx.yyy&category_id=zzz
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)/([0-9]+) $1.php?games_path=$1.swf&category_id=$2 [NC,L]
```

www.funkygames.co/games/achilles/1

Comment: The folder games has to be in the public_html folder. Not sure if that's the case from your phrasing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code in public_html/htaccess

```
# Turn Rewrite Engine On
RewriteEngine on

#Rewrite for achilles.php?games_path=xxxxxxxxxxxxx&category_id=x
RewriteRule ^(?:(achilles|games)/)?([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ /achilles.php?games_path=$1.swf&category_id=$2 [NC,L]
```

This will rewrite :

- http://example.com/achilles/achilles/1

or

- http://example.com/achilles/1

or

- http://example.com/games/achilles/achilles/1

to

- /achilles.php?games_path=achilles.swf&category_id=1

Comment: `Not Found

The requested URL /achilles/achilles/1 was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.`

Did not work but it looks interesting. Perhaps if you showed me what "?",":" and "$" do i could rearrange things around and see if something happens.

Answer (score 0):

In the `.htaccess` file stored in the `games` folder, insert the following:

```bash
RewriteEngine On

# Set the base to /games/ so we need not include it in the rules

RewriteBase /games/

# Rewrite {something}/{id} to {something}.php?games_path={something}&category_id={id}
# Examples: achilles/1 -> achilles.php?games_path=achilles.swf&category_id=1
#           other/3 -> other.php?games_path=other.swf&category_id=3

RewriteRule ^([0-9a-z]+)/(\d+)/?$ $1.php?games_path=$1&category_id=$2 [NC,L]
```

In this example, a trailing slash is made optional. If you do not want the trailing slash, remove `/?` from the request pattern. Also, this examples assumes that the first part of the request pattern will match the existing PHP file. If you want to use only `achilles.php`, then replace `$1.php` with `achilles.php`.